# How to create my own murder mystery game?

Tags: game, puzzle-creation, mystery

I’m hosting a game night next week at a local bar, and. I wanted to have a segment with a murder mystery. The owner of the bar has agreed to be the deceased victim, and four people who regularly attend have agreed to be the suspects.

It can’t be an hours long affair, it will be one 15-20 minute segment among several others (its mostly a trivia night, I’ll be making a detour with this mystery thing)

I was thinking of adapting this to be a murder mystery:

[Who is the thief? An elementary school teacher had her purse stolen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/who-is-the-thief-an-elementary-school-teacher-had-her-purse-stolen?rq=1)

With the players having to identify the one murderer and an accomplice.

How would you proceed? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One idea I use frequently is to give each of the four 'players' an identity and story. They learn to this story. Then place all the names in a hat and pick a 'murderer' at random. The detective asks the questions, and the murderer is somehow compromised by the lotto draw.

They must adhere to their story I suppose, and only the murderer is allowed to lie? No blatant 'was it you' questions are allowed.